# How to use Amazon Cognito with Facebook Authentication?

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api

I just started to learn AWS MobileHub and Cognito feature. I have a project which only required sign-in with Facebook.

In generated sample code I can see the process for user login and everything works fine. I am asking for a public_profile facebook permission and I must have access to user's email address. Now I want to store user's email address and retrieve it every time user login.

1. Do I need to save this data in dynamodb or cognito
2. I was wondering federated identity is what I need or I need to create a new user pool?
3. How can I get user's email address. Can I access it through AWS libraries or I must call the user's graph and ask for these information?
4. Can I save these data in `[AWSIdentityManager defaultIdentityManager]`
5. Is there any sample app displaying how to save information comes from facebook.

What I can see now is AWS got the userName and photo and ID from Facebook. But I can not see where these information come from and where they set up. Do I need to create a new pool and add attribute to that pool? Is there any sample app code with more detail regarding Facebook login?